# Free the memory of a std::vector C++

Tags: c++, mfc, stdvector

I have a vector as below.

```
std::vector<std::string> exportNameList;
```

I am adding elements to this by using push_back method. But I am getting a debug assertion as "

> "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in AxCent.exe.This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in AxCent.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This happens when it calls the destructor of the class. When I refer to the call stack I was directed to the following code block in the vector class.

```
~vector()
{   // destroy the object
    _Tidy();
}
```

What I noticed is there is an error when deleting the vector. Am I correct? How do I fix this? I have referred to many examples, but did not manage to work this out yet. I am quite new to C++.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you show the real declaration of your vector? What type of object do you store inside?

Comment: hi. what exactly is your problem? when `exportNameList` gets out of scope, the vector memory gets freed. for the elements it depends.

Comment: and show your code for the destructor of the class that has this member.

Comment: present a complete but minimal example that exhibits the problematic behavior

Comment: I am sorry if I sound stupid. The program is crashing after calling the following line : OCCViewer::~OCCViewer(void)
{
    delete m_impl; 
} where m_impl is a struct in the header file where the exportNamelist is declared. Should I delete the vector here? Please give me your ideas.

Comment: If you are on Linux you should use Valgrind to debug this.

Comment: Does m_impl have a destructor?  Please tell me its not calling `delete &exportNameList`

Comment: Are you creating and deleting your vector in the same module? Things might go crazy if you create an object in DLL and destroy in the main EXE.

Comment: @Alan- m_impl does not have a destructor but it is not calling delete &exportNameList. Thanks.

Comment: @ks1322 I am using windows 7.

Comment: @grep - Yes. I am creating it in the heap, but dont delete it anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Check all pieces of code where you are manipulating the contents of the vector, eg keep a close eye on function calls or pieces of code that use a reference/pinter of the objects of vector and modify them. My best guess is the objects of vector are deleted much before the destructor of the vector is called.

Answer (score 5):

You are presumably corrupting the memory used by the vector somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please give me any clue? I am getting this error only in the debug mode. Thanks.

Comment: You should re-check the relevant parts of your application (a good point to start would be all places where the vector in question or its elements are accessed). If possible, try to cut the size of the program until you can locate the error. We can't help you on that, I'm afraid.

Comment: @gishu If you don't know how you can corrupt the vector somewhere else in your program, imagine this: You have a pointer that is pointing to the wrong location (by chance, that happened to be the vector). You write to it and the vector gets corrupt. A more likely situation is this: You have an array on the stack next to the vector. You write to an index of the array, out of the boundaries of the array, and you go over the vector data and corrupt it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice Shahbaz. I will check the code for them.

Answer (score 1):

The bug you encounter may not be directly related to your vector.
If the memory (heap) is corrupted before the destructor of your vector is called, then the heap manager may only detect the corruption at this time (freeing the structure dynamically allocated by the vector or the dynamically allocated strings inside).

In my opinion, the best way to handle these kinds of bugs on the Windows platform is to activate the Full Page Heap for your program.

You can do this in 2 ways :

- either using gflags contained in the 'Debugging Tools for Windows'. Run it as administrator, go to the 'Image File' tab, enter the name of your EXE in the Image field (AxCent.exe), press TAB and check 'Enable page heap' and press 'Apply'
- or use Application Verifier. Select your executable through the File/App application menu make sur the check 'Basics/Heap' is checked and click save.

This setting will be applied whenever this application is launched.

Then run your application under a debugger (WindDbg or Visual Studio). If the memory is corrupted before your vector deletion, the debugger should break at this point.

When you are finished tracking the bug, don't forget to turn Full Page Heap off.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thierry. I dont will tried to use 'Debugging Tools for Windows', but found it is so complex. Anyway I will give it a try again.Thanks again.

Comment: The debuggers contained inside 'Debugging Tools for Windows' (WinDbg, kd, cdb) may frighten you at first. I can understand, but it is very valuable to known these tools. gflags, contained in the same package, is only a small interface to configure the registry so that Windows apply some policies to your application. It is very easy to use and, for the particular problem you encounter, Visual Studio should be enough to pinpoint your problem.